# Classic Google Analytics custom report not showing events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've set up Google Tag Manager to send events with custom variables to a Classic Google Analytics account. Each environment I'm testing on (development and qa) has its own GTM and GA accounts with essentially the same setup--really the only difference is the domain I'm passing in to GA's cookie domain.

I set up reports for these events with custom variables so that I could see the values of the custom variables. The development environment registers events and reports custom variables correctly.

However, the qa environment registers the events--I can see them happening real time--but when I create the same, working custom report I have in development the report just says there is no data.

I've messed around with the report date window, refreshed the report, tried showing different variables...and none of these will get the report in qa to show data.

How long does it take for a recorded event to show up on one of these reports? Does the cookie domain effect custom reporting? What factors could affect how long it takes for the report to show the correct data?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm coming up with the exact same problem at the moment...

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to figure this out, I ended up just not using custom reporting and custom variables and instead just used event labels with real-time reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. At the time I setup the custom report no events had gone into Google Analytics. I couldn't see the 'Event Label' dimension even after events had been logged.

However when I created a new report from scratch it was working. So as a workaround you could try that.